# how i can select data from a combo box and fires onchange command using VBA-excel

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

i want to select "56 - Hoyer (Suk / Rontec)" in the combo box and then fire the event that reloads the page using VBA excel, i can put the text on the combo box, but it doesnt load tha javascript attached to it (onchange event).

[see image of the drop down / combo box here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBAsa.jpg)

below is the code i use in VBA to fill out the combobox with a constant value. but i cannot run the onchange event on html provided.

```
Call IE.document.getElementById("orders.carrier_number_txtSelectionDisplay").setAttribute("value", "56 - Hoyer (Suk / Rontec)")
Call IE.document.getElementById("orders.carrier_number_txtSelectionDisplay").setAttribute("value", "56 - Hoyer (Suk / Rontec)")

Set x = IE.document.getElementById(orders.carrier_number_txtSelectedValue)
       x.Focus
       x.FireEvent "onchange"
```

Below is the HTML code:

```
<td>
<div>
    <span id="Descriptor.orders.carrier_number" class="dataentry-descriptor dataentry-descriptor-top" style="text-align:left;">Carrier</span>
</div>
    <div class="dataentry-field-control" style="text-align:left;">
        <div id="orders.carrier_number_4b7bc829-2760-4042-aab0-be8ccfb9541b" timerid="" querymethodname="GetSupplierCarriers">
            <div id="orders.carrier_number_pnlSelectionDisplay" class="ffnet-combo-box dataentry-field required" style="width:180px;">
                <table border="0" style="border-spacing: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; margin:0px;">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col style="width: 100%"> 
                        <col style="width: 30px; text-align: right;"> 
                    </colgroup> 
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 0px;">
                                <input name="orders.carrier_number$txtSelectionDisplay" type="text" id="orders.carrier_number_txtSelectionDisplay" class="dataentry-field required  validate[required] required" isrequired="True" datatype="3"
                                onkeydown="javascript:return InputProcessKeyDown('orders.carrier_number_4b7bc829-2760-4042-aab0-be8ccfb9541b', event);" onfocus="javascript:return InputProcessOnFocus('orders.carrier_number_4b7bc829-2760-4042-aab0-be8ccfb9541b');
                                " style="width:150px;"> 
                                <input name="orders.carrier_number$txtSelectedValue" type="text" onchange="retrieveChildData(&quot;orders.carrier_number_4b7bc829-2760-4042-aab0-be8ccfb9541b&quot;,&quot;orders.loaded_driver_number_e5ba36ca-
                                aa0f-4f55-aa3e-c7cb342d0b0b&quot;); retrieveChildData(&quot;orders.carrier_number_4b7bc829-2760-4042-aab0-be8ccfb9541b&quot;,&quot;orders.delivered_driver_number_e7747c68-df71-4774-9b04-
                                d897d1fd9833&quot;); retrieveChildData(&quot;orders.carrier_number_4b7bc829-2760-4042-aab0-be8ccfb9541b&quot;,&quot;orders.vehicle_code_d3cc805c-e505-45c5-a351-98028439e34d&quot;); retrieveChildData(&quot;orders.carrier_number_4b7bc829-
                                2760-4042-aab0-be8ccfb9541b&quot;,&quot;orders.tractor_number_089faa52-6810-4815-8f64-81eb201105a2&quot;); UpdateDirtyBit(1);setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'orders.carrier_number$txtSelectedValue\',\'\')', 0)"
                                onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" id="orders.carrier_number_txtSelectedValue" datavaluefield="carrier_number" assembly="FFNET_CORE" funcname="OrderDispatch_DeleteOrderTrailer"
                                methodclass="CBL" hasautopostback="true" namespace="FBS" selectlistargs="{&quot;SenderId&quot;:&quot;orders.carrier_number&quot;,&quot;supplier_number&quot;:&quot;139&quot;,&quot;RequiresParent&quot;:&quot;True&quot;}" style="display:none;">
                            </td>
                            <td> 
                                <img id="orders.carrier_number_imgArrow" onclick="InputProcessOnFocus('orders.carrier_number_4b7bc829-2760-4042-aab0-be8ccfb9541b'); activeCB.toggleDropDown();" src="/ffnet/Images/DropDownListArrow.gif">
                            </td>
                        </tr> 
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div id="orders.carrier_number_pnlDropDownList" class="ffnet-combo-box-ddlist" style="width:339px;">
                <div id="orders.carrier_number_pnlDropDownRegion" class="ffnet-combo-box-ddregion" value="" style="width:339px;">
                    <table header="0" style="width:322px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <colgroup>
                            <col style="width:80px;">
                            <col style="width:210px;">
                        </colgroup>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr> 
                                <th>Carrier Number</th>
                                <th>Name</th> 
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                <div id="orders.carrier_number_pnlDataRegion" class="ffnet-combo-box-data" style="width:339px;height:200px;">
                    <table style="width:322px;" onkeydown="javascript:return ProcessKeyDown(this, event);" tabindex="0" mode="combobox">
                        <colgroup>
                            <col style="width:80px;">
                            <col style="width:210px;">
                        </colgroup>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr id="orders.carrier_number_tr0" pk="1" text="1 - Armac Shipping" class="ffnet-combo-box-row-focus">
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>Armac Shipping</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="orders.carrier_number_tr1" pk="2" text="2 - IPCS Ltd">
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>IPCS Ltd</td>
                            </tr>                       
                            <tr id="orders.carrier_number_tr23" pk="56" text="56 - Hoyer (Suk / Rontec)">
                                <td>56</td>
                                <td>Hoyer (Suk / Rontec)</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="orders.carrier_number_pnlPager" class="ffnet-combo-box-paging" title="Click for more records" onclick="RetrieveNextPage($(&quot;[id$='orders.carrier_number_4b7bc829-2760-4042-aab0-be8ccfb9541b']&quot;).get(0), false);
                " recordcount="129">

    1-30 of 129 results
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="orders.carrier_number_txtSelectedValue_hdnDirtyBit" id="orders.carrier_number_txtSelectedValue_hdnDirtyBit" value="0">
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried x.FireEvent("onchange")

Comment: If the code in your post is a copy and paste, you are missing the quotation marks in Set x = IE.document.getElementById(orders.carrier_number_txtSelectedValue)

Comment: are you sure that setting `value` on a div element is correct? can you provide the source of the javascript function `ProcessKeyDown`

Comment: In your HTML code, I did not find any HTML element with ID=orders.carrier_number_txtSelectionDisplay for which you had try to set value and I did not find the element 'orders.carrier_number_txtSelectedValue', Which you are trying to focus and fire it's change event. I suggest you to check the ID of dropdown from developer tools and than try to make a test with it.

Comment: @Alex yes i have, but im having a null object error.

Comment: @RicardoA hmmm let me check on that one.

Comment: @NickSlash Im setting a value in a combo box with input element (HTML codes updated.) as that specific combo box reloads the page when a value is selected.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT yes you are correct, there are some missing html codes there, and i have updated it now.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: Did you also try ie.document.querySelector("[id='orders.carrier_number_tr23']").click ?

Comment: You might be better off calling the underlying JavaScript that populates the form elements directly.